# AJAX database update with CSS button color change using Codeigniter

Tags: javascript, css, ajax, codeigniter, checkbox

I've seen good posts here of bits and pieces of what I am attempting to do, but nothing with all areas addressed. Does anybody have any code examples or advice to help me do what I am trying to do?

First, I will build my MVC view with an array of data such as (org name, id, status) where status is a boolean value, either selected or unselected.  However, rather than showing a mere checkbox, I'd like to display a particular  showing either a green (selected) or red (not selected) button based on the state of the database value. CSS is not an issue.

Then, if and when a user clicks the button, I would like to change the div value from red to green (or vice versa), but also update the boolean value in the database field via an AJAX call.  It would be preferable to leverage JQuery where possible.

Finally, I need to know how to do this all using CodeIgniter.  I am well versed in CI but a Javascript/JQuery newbie - deer in the headlights at this point.  Can anyone point me in the right direction or suggest a web site with some sample code close to what I am trying to do or a good resource other than the obvious?  Thank you kindly.

Answer (score 3):

OK, so CodeIgniter is a PHP framework - which means it works server-side. (I know, there's an ajax library in there, but I don't use that.) We have to understand the difference between server-side and client-side. Your javascript is client-side. I usually develop everything without javascript to begin with in codeigniter, then go back and add the javascript bits. This helps me to ensure that the system works for those that don't have javascript turned on, or can't execute javascript for whatever reason. (BTW, this is called [progressive enhancement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Progressive_enhancement)).

So, first, let's take care of the non-javascript version:
You just need to give your red/green button a url when clicked that points to the controller method that will update the database record and redirect you back to the page that you were previously on (which has the red/green buttons).

/controller/method.html is our controller method that will save to the database and redirect back to this page. -->

```
<a href="/controller/method.html" class="red my-button">Check</a>
```

Now, let's take care of the js version:

in your view, you just need to hijack the click, send the ajax request, and change the red/green button based on the result from the controller method. So, what we do is keep the link from redirecting the page to the href attribute (e.prevendDefault()). Then, we get the value of the href and make an ajax call to that controller method. The method will determine if this is an ajax request and save to the database, then echo back a "success" message. On `success`, we can update the visual component on the client side.

```
$('.my-button').live('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        // $(this).attr('href') gets the value of the links href attribute 
        // which is "/controller/method.html" in this case
        url: $(this).attr('href'), 
        success: function(data) {
           // update your button with whatever html to write the new button
           $('.my-button').replaceWith('<a href="/controller/method.html" class="red my-button">Check</a>');
        }
    });
});
```

Your controller method just checks if it is an ajax request or not. If so, just returns success, if not redirects the page.

```
function my_controller_method()
{
    if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && 
        $_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']=="XMLHttpRequest") {

        // update your database
        echo "success";
    }else{
        // redirect back to page
        redirect($_SERVER[‘HTTP_REFERER’]);
    } 
}
```

Comment: Awesome!  Thank you for your time and effort.  I'll go over this and figure out what the code is doing.  Once I get my head wrapped around it, I'll post back anything additional which will help others to quickly come up to speed as well.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is sort of a thumbs up / like thingy...there's a demo included in the link http://www.geertdedeckere.be/lab/themeforest/thumbsup/demo/

Comment: Very good resources to keep in mind.  Thank you.  I have it bookmarked.